# intercept copy, paste, define popover in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

When we highlight a text in UIWebView usually the copy, paste, define.. etc appears. How can I intercept this so that when I choose copy I call some other method/do something else. Is this possible?

Comment: Here a sample: http://goo.gl/lLJpL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply override -copy:

```
- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
    // Do something else here
    return [super copy:sender];
}
```

**Edit to answer your comment.**

Define is a bit trickier, since it's private. However, you could implement your own method. Set up the UIMenuController with your desired items.

```
UIMenuItem *copyItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" 
                                                  action:@selector(myCopy:)];

UIMenuItem *defineItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Define"
                                                    action:@selector(myDefine:)];

[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:defineItem, copyItem, nil]];
[defineItem release];
[copyItem release];
```

Then you implement those methods.

As for define, it's way more complicated.. First, you need to check if the UIReferenceLibraryController has a definition, by overriding -canPerformAction:withSender:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (action == @selector(myDefine:)) {
        // Make sure we are on iOS5.x
        if (NSClassFromString(@"UIReferenceLibraryViewController")) {
            return [UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:[webView selectedText]];
        }
    }
    // Implement other custom actions here
    return NO;
}
```

-selectedText is here a category on UIWebView:

```
- (NSString *)selectedText {
    return [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
}
```

Then you need to implement myDefine:

```
- (void)myDefine:(UIMenuController *)menuController 
{    
    CGRect selectedWordFrame = [webView rectForSelectedText];

    UIReferenceLibraryViewController *dict = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:[webView selectedText]];
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dict];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:selectedWordFrame
                             inView:webView
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                           animated:YES];
    [popover setDelegate:self];
    [dict release];
}
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController 
{
    [popoverController release];
}
```

**Edit to answer you comment again**

-rectForSelectedText is another custom category on UIWebView.

```
- (CGRect)rectForSelectedText {
    return CGRectFromString([self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getRectForSelectedWord()"]);
}
```

What it does is calling a javascript that returns a string that you can convert using CGRectFromString(), it looks something like this:

```
function getRectForSelectedWord() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    return "{{" + rect.left + "," + rect.top + "}, {" + rect.width + "," + rect.height + "}}";
}
```

Check [this page](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview) to learn how to inject javascript into UIWebView.

Comment: oh and by the way this is on the iPhone so when I tried it, it gives me called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Comment: also trying this gives me three menu popover, copy, define, define

Comment: Right, you should return NO in -canPerformAction:withSender.

Comment: returning NO gives me the same result, there's only one more problem left, which is how to remove the define menu in the popover, so I will only have one define, which is mine

Comment: @adit Are you returning YES from any other method further up in the responder chain? Apple's note on canPerformAction:withSender: _Note that if your class returns NO for a command, another responder further up the responder chain may still return YES, enabling the command._

Comment: @hwaxxer How do you override `-canPerformAction:withSender:` on a `UIWebView`? (The Question is specifically targeting UIWebView not other widgets.) Apple doc says not to subclass UIWebView. If using a category, how do you use place the category on a xib?

Comment: @BasilBourque `canPerformAction:withSender:` propagates through the `UIResponder` chain, so you don't have to override `UIWebView`.